# How to output the contents of file_get_contents

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to figure out how to get a php file (html, css and javascript) and load it into the `content` section below.

The following is the original...

```
function wpse_124979_add_help_tabs() {

    if ($screen = get_current_screen()) {
        $help_tabs = $screen->get_help_tabs();
        $screen->remove_help_tabs();
        $screen->add_help_tab(array(
            'id' => 'my_help_tab',
            'title' => 'Help',
            'content' =>  'HTML CONTENT',
```

I have tried the following but fails. I added a `file_get_contents` (first line), and then tried pull it in with `'content' =>  $adminhelp`,

The following is with my amended code...

```
$adminhelp = file_get_contents('admin-help.php'); 

function wpse_124979_add_help_tabs() {

    if ($screen = get_current_screen()) {
        $help_tabs = $screen->get_help_tabs();
        $screen->remove_help_tabs();
        $screen->add_help_tab(array(
            'id' => 'my_help_tab',
            'title' => 'WTV Help',
            'content' =>  $adminhelp,
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Your `$adminhelp` variable isn't in scope in the function - you either need to pass it in, or move that line inside the function. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Just as @iainn said, you're calling `$adminhelp` from outside the scope. Move `$adminhelp = file_get_contents('admin-help.php'); ` inside your function.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the output of the PHP file to be saved as $adminhelp use:

```
$adminhelp = file_get_contents('http://YOUR_DOMAIN/admin-help.php');
```

Right now you're loading the source code of admin-help.php into $adminhelp.

Another example for getting the output of a webpage is cURL:

```
// create curl resource 
$ch = curl_init(); 

// set url 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://YOUR_DOMAIN/admin-help.php"); 

//return the transfer as a string 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

// $output contains the output string 
$adminhelp = curl_exec($ch); 

// close curl resource to free up system resources 
curl_close($ch);
```

If this doesn't answer your question, please include the error message that you're receiving.

Comment: Thanks, I did need to use the full URL. Thanks.